# Use the same common parameters for all openvpn config files

Tags: networking, openvpn, vpn

I have several openvpn `.conf` files for various vpns, and they all need to have these lines at the end of the file, like

```
script-security ...
setenv PATH ...
up ...
down ...
down-pre ...
```

Is there a way to set this configuration globally across all files or in openvpn somewhere? I don't want to modify any of the individual vpn files if it's possible to configure it someplace centrally or globally.

I'm starting the config files with `systemd`, so `sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@vpn1.service`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--config` command line option multiple times to merge configurations or also include the `config` option inside a config file to refer to others.

Source:[OpenVPN - Getting started How-To](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/GettingStartedwithOVPN)

Comment: I've updated my question to show that I'm starting the vpns with systemd, how could I pass the `--config` option to systemd? I don't want to include the config option inside the config file because there are a lot of config files, I'd rather do it centrally like in some openvpn or systemd central configuration.

Comment: You can edit/copy the systemd unit file to include the option as it calls openvpn. Also a good practice would be to remove the duplicate lines from existing configs (avoiding conflicts), hence you can just add the config entry as you do it. Would it be enough? I can add it to the answer...

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service` the systemd unit file you're referring to? How exactly can I modify that file to add the 5 config params I need to from the question? Ideally I could create a single file with just those 5 lines it and refer to it in the unit file so that so I can add just one thing to that unit file instead of 5 things.

Comment: It's pretty much that what I am suggesting. You can "override" the openvpn unit file, updating the `ExecStart=` line to include an extra `--config path/to/conf`, where you can have as many parameters as you'd like. If your unit doesn't have such line, please add it to the question so I can figure it out, but mine does. Tell me so I can update the answer accordingly...